# asp dropdownlist inside bootstrap modal doesn't change value

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a web application using asp.net and bootstrap v3. On my page, there is a modal which contains two twxt boxes and an asp dropdownlist.
My problem is that the dropdownlist SelectedIndexChanged is not firing. When I put a dropdownlist outside the Modal, its SelectedIndexChanged fires without any problem. 
I have set the EnableViewState="true" for the Page and the DDL. I have also set AutoPostBack = "True".
Note:
The page postback when i change the selected item in the DDL inside the modal but it don't go to the SelectedIndexChanged event as i have put a break point and it doesn't work.
I have notices also that the HTML of the DDL (Option, Select) is also that the (Selected="Selected") property is always set for the first element.

this is how I loadt the DDL

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!isPostBack)
{
      DataSet ds2 = MainModule.GetTableSQLBySP(new Dictionary<string, string>(), "SP_Stand_GetSectorTypes");
    ddlMdlAreaInvitedSecType.DataSource = ds2.Tables[0];
    ddlMdlAreaInvitedSecType.DataValueField = "Set_ID";
    ddlMdlAreaInvitedSecType.DataTextField = "Set_LongName";
    ddlMdlAreaInvitedSecType.DataBind();    }
```

}

and this is the Modal code

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="modalAreaInvitedSearch" style="margin-top: 155px" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">Please enter product data  </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="height:auto">

                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MM" style="display: none" runat="server" id="Text1" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Short Name</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <asp:TextBox   enableviewstate="true" class="form-control " runat="server" id="txtMdlAreaInvitedShortName" />
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Long Name</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <asp:TextBox   enableviewstate="true" class="form-control " runat="server" id="txtMdlAreaInvitedLongName" />
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Sector Type</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <asp:DropDownList EnableViewState="true" class="form-control" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMdlAreaInvitedSecType_SelectedIndexChanged"  AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" ID="ddlMdlAreaInvitedSecType" />
                    </div>

                </div>


                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanel2" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:GridView ID="grdMdlAreaInvitedResult" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true"
                            DataKeyNames="Sec_Id" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered centerGridHead">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ShowHeader="false" ItemStyle-Width="17%">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%--<asp:LinkButton id="btnRemove" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Text="<i aria-hidden='true' class='icon-plus'></i>" CssClass="btn btn-info btn-xs "/>--%>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkGrdMdlAreaInvitedResult" runat="server"   CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs  " />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Sec_Id" HeaderText="Sec_Id" Visible="false" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Sec_ShortName" HeaderText="Sector" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Sec_LongName" HeaderText="Sector Long Name" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Sec_Id_Master" HeaderText="Sec_Id_Master" Visible ="false" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>

                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnMdlAreaInvitedSearch" EventName="Click" />
                       <%--  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlMdlAreaInvitedSecType" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />--%>
                    </Triggers>

                </asp:UpdatePanel>





            </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
                  <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="col-lg-12">

                        <asp:Button ID="btnMdlAreaInvitedClear" OnClientClick="clickCodeBtn()" runat="server"   class="btn btn-primary  col-lg-2" Text="Clear"></asp:Button>

                        <asp:Button ID="btnMdlAreaInvitedGet"  OnClientClick="clickCodeBtn()" runat="server" OnClick="btnMdlAreaInvitedGet_Click" class="btn btn-primary  col-lg-2" Text="Get"></asp:Button>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnMdlAreaInvitedSearch" UseSubmitBehavior="false"  runat="server" OnClick="btnMdlAreaInvitedSearch_Click" class="btn btn-primary  col-lg-2" Text="Search"></asp:Button>

                        <asp:Button ID="btnMdlAreaInvitedClose"  OnClientClick="clickCodeBtn()" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary  col-lg-2" Text="Close"></asp:Button>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

and this is how i open the Modal

```
 function popAreaInvitedSearch() {

        $('#modalAreaInvitedSearch').appendTo('body').modal({

            show: true,

            keyboard: false,

            backdrop: 'static'

        });

    }
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem to this with Fancybox, and it turned out that when the Modal loads, it extracts the HTML and injects it into a DIV **outside** of the main ASP.NET Form.

To correct this in Fancybox, I overrode the Fancybox source code to inject the Modal within the form.

I'd start by inspecting the page with Firebug, and identify where the Bootrap Modal is actually located.  If it is outside of the form, you will need to figure out how to get it rendered within for the ASP.NET control events to properly fire, which you perhaps can configure with the Modal javascript configuration options.

Hope that sets you on the right path.

Comment: I am using a masterpage so the DDL must bw inside the form.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the modal was out of the Form just like you said. When i put the modal in the form, the modal fades just like the page, but to solve this, i have removed the modal-backdrop class from the page by writing  $('.modal-backdrop').removeClass('modal-backdrop'); after opening the modal.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the DDL in the UpdatePanel as well? The DDL will most likely always result in a Postback now. Which is probably not desirable.

Comment: I have tried this as i must put it in update panel. I have removed the update panel just to c if it will postback or not ..